# html textarea injecting line breaks

Tags: html, css, textarea

I've got a weird problem.

I have an html textarea, with the cols set to 84, like so:

```
<textarea id="caseNote_note0" class="txtArea" name="caseNote_note" style="line-height: 1.1em; height: 5em;" wrap="hard" rows="10" cols="84" tabindex="7">blah blah blah</textarea>
```

The `txtArea` class is defined as:

```
.txtArea {
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            font-size:1.0em;
            width:99%;
            rows:10;
            overflow:hidden;
            border:none;
            font-family:arial,sans-serif;
            margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
        }
```

The textarea is stretched across almost the whole screen.

When the user types in data, the data all appears in the textarea as you would expect.

However, when you submit the form, the text looks like its been saved with line breaks injected into it.

i.e.

**before the save**:

*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah

*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

**after the save**:
*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

blah blah blah blah blah

*-------------------------------------------------------------------------------*

If I change the `cols` to be greater than 84 (say 150), the linebreaks appear later (i.e. more text shows before a line break seems to get enetered).

The text is also being saved in the database table with these apparent mystery line breaks.

A wordaround is to set the `cols` to something really high (like 500), then I guess I wouldn't run into this problem....but I'd rather know *why* this is happening in the first place.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Jarrett

Comment: Why are you settings the cols to 84 if you set the width to 99%?

Comment: @TheZ Not my code, I've been asked to fix it though :S

Comment: Well, what cols does is set the width to accommodate that many characters. The width 99% declaration overrides this and makes the width expand.

Comment: ahh...no idea why they set the cols to 84 then... :\  Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `wrap` attribute. It’s unneeded.

Comment: ahh that did it - not sure why they set the wrap, but there ya go.  I'll accept your answer when stackoverflow lets me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is caused by the `wrap="hard"` attribute in the HTML.  You can change it to `wrap="soft"` to wrap the lines on screen but not include them into the submitted data.  Alternatively you can change it to `wrap="off"` to turn wrap off completely - textarea will then include a horizontal scrollbar.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)'s one page describing this in details (this one is from Microsoft), but searching the web for *textarea wrap* will give you loads more.