# Display mulitline textbox value as multiline text on Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, textbox, crystal-reports

I am saving value from a `Multiline ASP.Net Textbox` into the `Database`.

```
<asp:TextBox id="txtDesc" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" width="300"></asp:TextBox>
```

It save the lines from `Textbox` separted by a Space in the database.

I want to display this value on the `Crystal Reports` exactly the same as entered in `Textbox` i.e multiline value. Currently, it displays `Textbox` value in a single line on reports.

**For understanding purpose :**

*Why multiline TextBox doesn't save any `<br/>` or `/n` with text in Database ?*

**OR**

*When getting back the value, how it differentiate different lines in a value* (mulitline value)

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From the following post: [html textarea injecting line breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198743/html-textarea-injecting-line-breaks), where the opposite problem was mentioned, you can use the `wrap="hard"` attribute to replace soft line breaks with hard ones in the TextBox:

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtDesc.Attributes.Add("wrap", "hard");
        ....
    }
}
```

On my Windows system, `\r\n` is inserted between lines.

According to my tests, the `wrap` attribute is maintained accross postbacks.